# Core Data design principles

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design

I just started reading this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1

And it basically has (in my opinion) two big contradictions:

[image]

I get them both, but basically, if I follow the first *"implement a custom class to the entity from which classes representing subentities also inherit"*-statement, then ALL my entities will be put in the same table. Which could cause performance issues, according to the *NOTE*.

How big of a performance hit would I run into of it create a "custom super entity"?

Comment: You mean one contradiction, two contradictory statements. (Although they aren't, actually.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inheritance mechanism to get a default database structure. From your link:

> If you have a number of entities that are similar, you can factor the common properties into a superentity, also known as a parent entity.

There is no contradiction. The documentation is just telling you what the database structure is going to be when you use a certain facility. (And it is the standard database table idiom for inheritance.) Using the entity inheritance mechanism automatically declares and implements default parent-child class inheritance functionality along with a parent table. Otherwise you do any parent-child class inheritance declaration and implementation by hand. Each comes with certain performance and other characteristics.

Design involves *tradeoffs* between *costs and benefits* over *multiple dimensions*. "Performance" itself involves multiple dimensions, and has no meaning outside of given application usage patterns. Other dimensions relevant here include complexity of both construction and maintenance.

If you query about entities as parents sufficiently frequently then it can be better to have all parent data in its own table. But if you sufficiently rarely ask for the parent data while querying about a given child type or if you sufficiently frequently need both child and parent data then it can be better to only have parent data in the child tables or table. But notice that each design performs worse at the other kind of query.

Comment: Well, here you say "parent table", but there will not be a parent table, "child types" and "parent types" will be in ONE table. "All entities that inherit from another entity will exist within the same table". I can also verify this locally in my own projects if I browse the database.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'll update my answer. Typically one table would mean, all attributes of all entities as columns, inapplicables as null. Can you confirm? Of course, it doesn't affect my point, just the tradeoffs. Eg if you did want parent & child tables, that's by hand.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. "By hand"? I can't modify the tables, then CoreData will break down.

Comment: I mean that if you don't use the inheritance functionality of the design tool then you use the non-inheritance functionality of the design tool. When a language doesn't have object inheritance built in, you can still design corresponding objects with the methods with the same behaviour and appropriate implementation/database state. The inheritance facility is just a convenience helping to enforce and reflect patterns in specified behaviour and its implementation. Maybe this is why you think there is a contradiction--you think there is no alternative?

Comment: There are two alternatives: **1.** Use the CoreData inheritance mechanism and then get all stuff in ONE table. **2.** Dont use CoreData inheritance. The contradiction is: the docs say it's neat to create a "super"-entity that all inherit from, but then it warns you that then everything is put in one table, which is bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

The first is talking about sub-entities. The second is talking about subclasses. These are 2 different hierarchies.

One use for sub-entities is if you have a table where you want to show cells displaying different entities. By making them sub-entities, you can fetch the parent entity and all sub-entities will be returned. This is actually how the Notes app shows the "All Notes" cell above folders, that is actually displaying the Account entity, and both Account and Folder are sub-entities of NoteContainer which is what is fetched. This does mean all of the rows are in the same table, but personally I have not experienced any performance problems but it is something to keep in mind when modifying the entities in other ways like indexes, relations or constraints for example.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with this quirk of SQLite, but modeling base class/subclass relationships are usually done with different tables. There is one table that represents the base class which contains attributes common to all derivative classes (Vehiclea) and a different table for each subclass which contain attributes unique to that subclass (Cars, Trains, Airplanes).

Performance is no better or worse than any entity normalized across different tables.

Comment: This question is not regarding the general case or how it's usually done. It's about the specific case of how sqlite is used in CoreData