# Combine two NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, core-data

Good afternoon! In my project I use `Core Data`, and must be inferred from the two Entity, but I can not figure out how to combine the results of the first and second `NSFetchedResultsController` one. Must you need in a single table with no separation into sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an abstract entity, from which both of your entities inherit.

Also, don't use two `NSFetchedResultsController` if you're only showing one `UITableView`, because how will you combine the two of them? How will you order it?

**Do like this instead:**

For example if you want to show `Car`s and `Motorcycle`s in the the `NSFetchedResultsController`, you create a class `Vehicle` and fetch `Vehicle`s instead. Then make sure you set the `Parent Entity` to `Vechicle` for both `Car` and `Motorcycle` in the coredata-model editor:

[image]

EDIT: Here's an answer suggesting the same thing (for fetch requests in general, not specifically `NSFetchedResultController` [Core data: any way to fetch multiple entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096250/core-data-any-way-to-fetch-multiple-entities))

Comment: This also denormalise the sqlite DB as mention on "Core data: any way to fetch multiple entities" comment by @Floyd.

Comment: Yepp. I've actually got a question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338492/core-data-design-principles